# What is causing the green light to stay green?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, awt

Sorry for the dumb question, its for my homework. I am supposed to make a traffic light that changes the light when a push button is pushed. I have it semi working, the problem I am encountering is that the green light is staying lit during the red phase. I am doing the same thing for all three phases so I do not understand why it only has a problem with that one phase. 
Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

int presses;

int gy=200;
int yy=130;
int ry=60;
int filly=ry;
int empty1=gy;
int empty2=yy;
private JButton push;
private JLabel label;
Color light=Color.RED;

public ButtonPanel () {
    presses=0;
    push=new JButton("Change Light");



    push.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    add(push);


    setBackground(Color.white);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    g.drawOval(120,gy,50,50);
    g.drawOval(120,yy,50,50);
    g.drawOval(120,ry,50,50);
    g.drawRect(95, 50, 100, 210);
    g.setColor(light);
    g.fillOval(120, filly, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillOval(120, empty1, 50, 50);
    g.fillOval(120, empty2, 50, 50);



}
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(presses);
        presses++;
        if(presses>2) {
            presses=0;
        }
        if(presses==0) {
            light=Color.red;
            filly=ry;
            System.out.println("check");
            empty1=gy;
            System.out.println("check");
            empty1=yy;
            repaint();
        }
        if(presses==1) {
            light=Color.yellow;
            filly=yy;
            empty1=ry;
            empty2=gy;
            repaint();
        }
        if(presses==2) {
            light=Color.green;
            filly=gy;
            empty1=ry;
            empty2=yy;
            repaint();
        }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is the frame and main method part if you want to compile it:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class TrafficFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame= new JFrame("Traffic Light");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ButtonPanel panel=new ButtonPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: I ran your project and couldn't find the error you're having. Every time I repeatedly click the button in your panel, it cycles through all the colours correctly

Comment: The fact that the behavior varies for others suggests that you probably need to move the contents of your `main` method into a Runnable, and pass that Runnable to [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)).  This is necessary because Swing methods and constructors are not allowed to be called in the main thread, or any thread other than the Event Dispatch Thread;  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/.

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger? That usually catches any errors that I have made.

Comment: @VGR - this isn't a concurrency or event dispatch thread issue - there's reasonably good code with separation of object model from paint cycles. It's just a minor error in logic for updating the model - see my answer below.

Comment: @Krease I repeat:  Swing methods and constructors are not allowed to be called in any thread other than the Event Dispatch Thread.  Violating this rule leads to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Custom painting should be done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` of your panel, not the paint() method.

Comment: @VGR I don't disagree with you -- All Swing components are implemented to be accessed from a single thread (the event dispatching thread). So there are no protections against concurrent access and concurrent changes of variables and field -- All I'm saying is that's not the cause of the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo to me. In that if block, you’re setting `empty1` twice, and not setting `empty2`.